# Apache2.4 and WSL2 is giving an Error 403

Tags: apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Problem:

The website is returning an Error: 403 when trying to access it. No information is being given in log files afaik.

### Version

```
Windows 10: Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.388)
WSL: Version 2
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-04-13T17:19:17
```

### Permissions

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 22 12:36 /var/www/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   27 Jul 22 12:36 /var/www/website -> /mnt/d/work/website/
drwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 22 11:00 /mnt/d/work/website/
```

### Apache2ctl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   website.localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf:1)
*:443                  website.localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf:10)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

### VirtualHost Config

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName www.website.local
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /mnt/d/work/website/public
        
    <Directory /mnt/d/work/website/public>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^public\.html$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . public.html [L]

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### Hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       www.website.local
```

### Logs

No entries in `access.log` or `error.log`???

Answer (score 3):

### Update 24-02-2021

ip address of wsl-linux are dynamic ip it will not work.
You just need to add two lines of code

```
127.0.0.1   www.website.local
::1         www.website.local
```

---

I also face same issue,
Step to fix this issue are pretty simple.

1. Run command

   $ ip a

   [image]

> copy ip address
> 2. press window button type notepad (run as administrator)
> 3. In notepad, File->open file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host
> 4. add line at bottom

```
172.19.170.24  www.website.local
```

I try to change /etc/hosts file with both 127.0.0.1 <my_vhost> and 172.19.170.24 <my_vhost>, but that didn't worked.

Comment: I think the `::1` syntax in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. It's a network error.

Run the `ip addr` command and find out your `eth0` IP address, and use that one for your
`hosts` file.

That's what worked for me, because just like your Apache configuration, mine was right as well.